# How to enable snappy for leveldb cache in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, anaconda, leveldb, snappy

How to enable it or check, that Snappy is enabled for LevelDb cache in Scrapy? I've installed

`conda install -c conda-forge snappy`

`conda install -c conda-forge python-snappy`

`conda install -c anaconda leveldb`

`conda install -c anaconda python-leveldb`

and set in scrapy settings.py

`HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.LeveldbCacheStorage'`

and leveldb works fine, but how to enable snappy or check that snappy enabled for it? The thing is when I compressing cache with 7z I get about ~30x times less space. I understand, that snappy compression is all about speed, but with such numbers looks like it not enabled at all.
P.S. I'm using Windows 10 with Anaconda.

Comment: Are you try to compress data your cache DB by Snappy? From off doc - `Snappy is an order of magnitude faster for most inputs, but the resulting compressed files are anywhere from 20% to 100% bigger`. It's not a good solution I think. You can check if Level allow to use Snappy in source code

Comment: Looks like LevelDB support and use Snappy from the box